# How to re-enable slave server from RDS snapshot image

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have created an RDS instance that is working as a slave server of our on premises MySQL Master server. Means Master MySQL server is our Office Data Center MySQl server and its slave as this AWS RDS instance. Replication is working fine. I have enabled daily snapshot backup of this RDS instance.

As part of disaster recovery plan How can I rebuild a slave server with the existing snapshot backup, if the existing RDS slave down and not recoverable condition.
I tried this work around.

1. In master server, executed this command to create replication user "GRANT REPLICATION CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'slave'@'172.20.10.0/255.255.255.0' IDENTIFIED BY 'BYLhgfdW3';"
2. Created new RDS instance from the snapshot of a slave server.
3. Started slave using "CALL mysql.rds_start_replication; from this RDS instance"
   Getting some error when i check the Slave status from this RDS instance.

   Please let me know the work flow to enable this RDS instance as slave server

Comment: *"Getting some error"*.  You will need to be more specific about what the error is.  MySQL replication is a non-trivial subject, and your strategy may or may not be viable.

Comment: That's error (I have same question):
```
mysql> CALL mysql.rds_start_replication;
ERROR 1200 (HY000): The server is not configured as slave; fix in config file or with CHANGE MASTER TO
```
After restore slave from snapshot